# JComboBox: want first entry to be blank entry

Tags: java, swing, combobox, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I have a jcombobox which values come from a list. I want to first value to be blank from dropdown list. The way I approached it was by putting new object of the list type in first as example shows :

```
 final List<Object> list = getObjectsList();
  list.add(new Object());
```

But this results in null pointer and if do

```
list.add(null);
```

this solves the issue but then gives me another prob elsewhere with a Comparator method. So any work a rounds would be great thanks.

Comment: first of all, you should accept some answers, you have asked 7 question, you did not even accept any of them..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doesn't `JComboBox.insertItemAt("", 0);` work for you? You need to add validation for the blank entry too

Comment: Yea that's seems to have solved this nullpointer, so on to the next, Thanks

Answer (score 29):

You can also set the selected index to -1 after the items have been added, but before the event listener.

```
    JcomboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```

This solution will work better if your JcomboBox uses generics.

Comment: This option worked great for me to represent when my model has an invalid value, but I don't want the user to be able to enter invalid values. Once the user selects an item the blank "invalid" item cannot be selected again.

Comment: This is the most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it depends from what will you do with this "empty entry". Few ideas:

Try add empty string.

Add object/null AND override getSelectedIndex() method.